# Can't open Https TSL page with Delphi - Indy Error : SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO

Tags: delphi, ssl, https, indy, delphi-xe5

I want to read an HTML page via HTTPS using Indy's `TIdHTTP` in Delphi XE5.

`ssleay32.dll` and `libeay32.dll` are in the main program folder.

I am getting an error: `SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO`.  What can I do to fix this?

```
function get_page_text:string;
var
  Response: String;
  HTTPClient: TidHTTP;
const
  url = 'https://www.lustundreiz.com/login';
begin
  HTTPClient := TidHTTP.Create;
  HTTPClient.AllowCookies := True;
  HTTPClient.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  Response := HTTPClient.get(url);
  HTTPClient.Free;
  result := response;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default SSL/TLS version used by `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` when you don't specify a version is TLSv1, not SSLv23.  So it is very unusual for you to be getting an SSL23 error.

Many modern web servers now require TLS 1.1 or higher, TLS extensions like SNI, etc. So consider enabling `sslvTLSv1_1` and `sslvTLSv1_2` in the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions` property, in addition to the default `sslvTLSv1`.  And make sure you are using an up-to-date version of Indy and the OpenSSL DLLs to support those versions.

You should also wrap your code in a `try..finally` so you can `Free` the `TIdHTTP` object even if `Get()` raises an exception.

Try this:

```
function get_page_text:string;
var
  HTTPClient: TIdHTTP;
  SSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
const
  url = 'https://www.lustundreiz.com/login';
begin
  HTTPClient := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    HTTPClient.AllowCookies := True;
    // set other HTTP properties as needed...

    SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(HTTPClient);
    SSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
    // set other SSL properties as needed...
    HTTPClient.IOHandler := SSL;

    Result := HTTPClient.Get(url);
  finally
    HTTPClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, but if I copy you code into my IDE there is an error at Line : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(HTTPClient.IOHandler).SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];  Error: SSLVersions -> not known

Comment: @Ingo: sorry, typo on my part. I fixed it.

Comment: Yes ok, thx for your code update. But if I run your code I got the same Error. SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert hanschake failure

Comment: The full Errorcode is: Error. 14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert hanschake failure

Comment: @Ingo: using the latest versions of Indy and OpenSSL, the code I have shown works fine for me, there is no SSL error for the URL you have provided, I receive the HTML instead.  If you are using the version of Indy that ships with XE5, you should upgrade your Indy version

Comment: How can I Update Indy in XE5?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after I updated from Delphi XE5 to Delphi XE10 the Code works well without any Errors.
Thanks to Remy for the Support.