# I can not fix error routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

Tags: delphi, indy

I wrote this code to send email to gmail and another private mail server. here is the code:

```
IdMessage1.Recipients.EMailAddresses := lblFrom.Text;
IdMessage1.Subject := lblSubject.Text;
IdMessage1.Body.Text := Memo1.Text;

 IdSMTP1.Connect;
 IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);
 IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
```

but I get error on smtp.connect:

> error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

The component `IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1` has the `SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1]`

I tried to change it to `SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvSSLv3]` but I get error:

> error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol.

How to fix these problems ?

I am using Delphi Tokyo and Indy version 10.6.2.5366

Comment: Have you tried to [follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48450282/8041231)?

Comment: @Victoria yes I get unknown protocol error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wow I found it I had to set the `IdSMTP1.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS`